# Toggling an item on click?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to make a link between a list item and a div down the page.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul id="side-items">
    <li class="side-item" id="s1">side 1</li>
    <li class="side-item" id="s2">side 2</li>
    <li class="side-item" id="s3">side 3</li>
    <li class="side-item" id="s4">side 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="body">
  <div id="page1">
    Page1
  </div>
  <div id="page2">
    Page2
  </div>
  <div id="page3">
    Page3
  </div>
  <div id="page4">
    Page4
  </div>
</div>
```

My jQuery looks like this:

```
$("#s1").click(function() {
    $("#page1").toggle();
});

$("#s2").click(function() {
    $("#page2").toggle();
});

$("#s3").click(function() {
    $("#page3").toggle();
});

$("#s4").click(function() {
    $("#page4").toggle();
});
```

What I want is page number `n` to be toggled when you click item number `n`.

But, with this code nothing happens when you click a list item. I have jQuery linked like so:

```
<script src="./jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My question is why is this not working? Am I using the `$()` function incorrectly?

Comment: Any reason for using jQuery `1.1.1` ?

Comment: You need to wrap your jquery in $(function() { ... }

Comment: your `javascript` code must be after this `html` code

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uxizuv/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
$("#sidebar li").click(function() {
    $('.page').eq( $(this).index() ).show().siblings('.page').hide();
});
```

<sub>You don't need the `.siblings('.page').hide();` if you don't want to handle the other pages visibility</sub>

SIMPLIFIED HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>side 1</li>
    <li>side 2</li>
    <li>side 3</li>
    <li>side 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="body">
  <div class="page">
    Page1
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    Page2
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    Page3
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    Page4
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to hide all other divs when showing specific one withing onclick
Take a look at the markup for [jquery tabs()](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/). The link between `li` and target `div` is done via `href` attribute:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">tab1</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This pen shows that it is working: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IystC

Are you sure everything else is set up properly? Is the js file even included in the html?

Comment: I have the code javascript pasted into my head, should it not be there?

Comment: I would say it's better in a separate file, but putting in withing <script> in <head> works too. Is jQuery included correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#side-items li').click(function() {
    var index = $('#side-items li').index(this);
    $("#page" + (index+1)).toggle();
});
```